# ASP.NET MVC Razor page throws exceptions in another Razor page after edit until next build

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have Razor page with some content. Today I noticed that I can't edit this page (and only this) in runtime. After any edit, even if page stays the same, it simply throws `NullReferenceException` until I stop project and restart it.

What is really strange - is stacktrace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
  ASP._Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in 
  $PROJECTPATH$\obj\CodeGen\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:60
  System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
  System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +105
  System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
  ... and so on
```

the problem is that the file I edit is not `\Home\Index.cshtml`, but `\Areas\Configuration\Views\Home\Index.cshtml`. So Razor somehow starts pointing to the wrong file after any edit.
What I have tried:

- Exclude and include `\Areas\Configuration\Views\Home\Index.cshtml`.
- Totally recreate it
- Clean `obj` folders of whole solution
- Reload VS

Target file, `\Areas\Configuration\Views\Home\Index.cshtml`, is compiled successfully. I even tried to compile empty page, but it still throws exception in `\Home\Index.cshtml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found workaround by changing `View(model)` to `View("~/Areas/Configuration/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", model)`. But I'd like to know, what can cause Razor to pick page wrong after edit in debug.